# Instantly actualize other inputs. jQuery , Javascript Solution

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I want to actualize other inputs instantly.

The problem is that "keyup" is to late, and keydown event won't take the "actual" inserted char.

I created example that work as I want but i've used setTimeout...

```
$inputGood.keydown(function(){
    var $self = $(this);
    setTimeout(function(){$toUpdateGood.val($self.val())}, 30 ); 

})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZhPQ9/12/

Thank you for sharing the solution to this problem.

Comment: you could try keypress?

Comment: keypress works in this example as keydown (insert the value to late)

Comment: keyup seems to work fine

Comment: It's to late for me. You can press long key... and thi will not update fast enough.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $inputGood.onfocusout(function(){
       var $self = $(this);
       setTimeout(function(){$toUpdateGood.val($self.val())}, 30 ); 

   })
```

Would this satisfy your purposes?

Comment: 1. Your code doesn't make sense to me.
2. "onfocusout" seems to don't exists.
3. I want to inconstantly insert "after keypress" not after "foucus out"

Comment: i found info on onfocusout here [link] http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536936(v=vs.85).aspx although onBlur seems to be more popular, and I assumed after the keystroke that the focus was going to be moved to the next element. If you want to keep the focus on the element you could set it at the end of the function. onfocusout is IE only, onBlur for the rest